# Using Nifty GUI with Slick2D

Tags: java, gui, slick

As seen [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nifty-gui/index.php?title=Nifty_Slick_Renderer_%28Nifty_1.3.1%29#Loaders) NiftyGUI has it's own GameState classes, I want to know if for adding UI to one state of my game I need to make that state `NiftyOverlayGameState` or still a `BasicGameState` but to add a `NiftyOverlayGameState` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation you linked, here are the different implementions you will have to use based on the functionality you desire:

> - **NiftyGame, NiftyBasicGame** - Implementing the Game or the BasicGame, this classes are supposed to display only the Nifty-GUI
>     over the entire game.
> - **NiftyGameState, NiftyBasicGameState** - Implementing the GameState or the BasicGameState, this classes are supposed to display
>     only the Nifty-GUI over the entire state of the game. This can be
>     useful in for GUI-only states such as a login state.
> - **NiftyOverlayGame, NiftyOverlayBasicGame** - Implementing the Game or the BasicGame, this classes are supposed to display the Nifty-GUI
>     on top of something else. For example on top of the actual game
>     graphics.
> - **NiftyOverlayGameState, NiftyOverlayBasicGameState** - Implementing the GameState or the BasicGameState, this classes are
>     supposed to display the Nifty-GUI on top of something else, such as
>     the game graphics.
>
> This means if you want to add the NiftyGUI to just one state of your
>   game, you should probably use the **NiftyGameState** or
>   **NiftyBasicGameState**.

Then depending on your requirements you'll extend the Slick2D game state with this:

`protected void initGameAndGUI(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException;`

Then inside that you'll call this:

`protected final void initNifty(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, ...);`

For more details, read up on the <strike>Preparation and Slick2D-Game Implementations</strike> [manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nifty-gui/files/nifty-gui/).